# Clear cache of Microsoft Teams / Login with a different domain

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-teams

I have Microsoft Teams installed on my laptop (Kubuntu 20.04)

I used to use teams via my work account (while interning). (To log-in, enter work email on teams sign in page, redirects to company SSO, enter credentials, and I am inside teams)

Now that I'm done with my internship, I want to use my school's teams account, but am stuck at the company's SSO page, with no option to switch to a different domain. The only fields present are Username and Password, and entering any other username (of different domain) gives me an error "Could not find this account".

My work email has been deactivated.

I have tried uninstalling teams via `sudo apt --purge remove teams` and installing again (downloaded the .deb), but am still greated with the company's SSO.

Also Tried uninstalling via `sudo apt remove teams` and deleting teams folder under `~/.config/` and then restarting my laptop, installing teams again, but somehow the company's SSO still shows up.

**Summary of the question**

I open Teams, I see the company's SSO, can't sign-in using my work account as its deactivated. Can't enter domain that doesn't match the company's domain (gives error, if I do so), need to use school's teams account. How?

**EDIT**

Running with sudo (`sudo teams`), I get Microsoft's sign in to your account page, and can now access my school's teams account.
How do I reset teams to this behaviour,so that I get Microsoft's sign in page without using sudo?

Comment: Try installing Teams as a snap: `sudo snap install teams-for-linux`

Comment: Have tried the snap version, its glitchy (no notification, hangs). Would prefer the official one instead.

Comment: Try to use Teams under another user account and then replace with it your `~/.config/`.

Comment: @harrymc, tried, doesn't work :(

Comment: Did the other user account show the same problem? Do you have installed any other Office apps?

Comment: I copied the `~/.config/teams` from a different laptop, running the same Kubuntu 20.04 OS & Latest Teams [The other laptop does not have this issue, however, it still persists on mine].

No, I don't have any other Office apps installed.

I am signed out of the work account, but the SSO page opens up when I run teams.

Comment: Try using a new user account on same computer, just for information. Try also answer by  DeanPike1 on [this page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/delete-account-microsoft-teams/4eec135b-bb28-41b3-819c-aefbe187d207?page=2).

Comment: I was unable to view the contents of the chat. Was there ever any conclusion?

Comment: @BenMares, I had a requirement to switch to Kubuntu 20.10, hence performed a full format. Teams is working as expected here. However, you could try deleting the Microsoft folder under the .config folder via `sudo rm -rf ~/.config/Microsoft`, then restarting your computer, please report if that fixes the issue. Would be helpful, cheers!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

- Close Teams
- Rename the folder /home/$username/.config/Microsoft/Microsoft Teams
- Rename the folder /home/$username/.config/Microsoft/Microsoft Teams2
- Restart Teams, then login.

Answer (score 3):

Answer for **Teams in ubuntu**.
Purge and autoremove do not remove the configuration file that is present there and it will use same configuration if you install app again.

So, you need to remove configuration file.

1. Get list of all Microsoft related configuartion file.

```
    cd ~/.config
    ls
```

2. Remove the directories containing configuration for MS Teams

```
    rm -rf Microsoft
    rm -rf 'Microsoft Teams - Preview'
```

For any browser, clear all the cookies and cache from settings in browser.

Comment: Worked, but for me it was not in `~/.config` but in `/snap/teams-insiders/10/.config/` to find it I used `find . -name "*teams*"`